# Firefox on drag end is not called in a react component

Tags: firefox, drag-and-drop, reactjs

I am trying to implement a really basic drag and drop functionality with the HTML5 drag and drop api inside a React component. I need only to get notified when the drag started and when ended. While this works fine in Chrome and IE11 I don't get any notification for drag end in latest firefox. You can see an example here

http://jsbin.com/lifico/edit?js,console,output

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Firefox you need to set some data in the dataTransfer member of the event when the drag start. In your case you can just set an empty string:

```
onDragStart={(e) => {
             e.dataTransfer.setData('text',''); 
             console.log('drag start');}}
```

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations#dragdata).

Comment: Yes that solved the problem for me. Unfortunately I can't vote as answer

Comment: That's ok as long as it solved your problem. Cheers.